# Caddyfile header directive unable to override file_server ETag

Tags: http-headers, caddy

Invoking `caddy run` against the Caddyfile:

```
http://localhost
header ETag forcedValue
file_server
```

I expect `curl -v http://localhost/Caddyfile` to show a response with the ETag `forcedValue`.

Instead, a generated tag based on the Caddyfile's mtime and size is returned.

---

Things attempted:

- `order header before file_server` / `order header after file_server`
- tested whether `header -ETag` can *remove* the etag altogether (it does).

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `defer` flag allows the ETag set by `file_server` to be overridden.

```
http://localhost
header {
  ETag forcedValue
  defer
}
file_server
```